# How to show Form on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have navbar with 2 buttons where i want when click specific button to open their form, but seems javascript is not working.

As code is big im giving you a snippet for form and navbar on demo please check bellow:

Here is **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/m87rBKROdD)**

I have post my whole css so there you can see some junk stuff.

I have try with bootstrap modals but still is not working.

Comment: i have give snippet on demo only for what im neading

Comment: your *form-section* has *style="display: none;"* .how do you expect to click on something not visibile?

Comment: seems you dont get the point or i write wrong title, on click i want to change display:none to display:block to show that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BUTTON] = ID/Class of the button.
[FORM] = ID that you gave the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[BUTTON]").on("click", function(){
        $("[FORM]").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Or you can do it with change the css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[BUTTON]").on("click", function(){
        $("[FORM]").css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Comment: i dont want to slideDown i want to show up. Like change style from dsiplay:none; to display:block;

Comment: Thanks, i have try it but still same.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/dLQWQs2Ynp here i give you more detailed snipped, I have to make Login and Book Now forms visible on click.

Comment: Does this website include jquery scripts?

Comment: only some functions to stick navbar at top as you can see on snippet where i provide

Comment: its nowhere else is used that id which is used for the div for form. Which is #login-form

Comment: The button had this ID: `#app-login-button`

Comment: im writing jquery like that but still nothings happens
http://jsfiddle.net/09sb3nmy/

Comment: Sorry, i just see that your code is work seems problem to dont pop up its comes from somewhere else maybe some bootstrap problem